# Angular 4 - how to properly tear down the application?

Tags: angular

I need to remove the currently running Angular application from the website and I was trying to do that by getting rid of the HTML app node. However I discovered recently side effects of doing so i.e. some callbacks that Angular installed were not removed.

What is then the proper way to tear down an Angular 4 application?

The current approach that I'm using doesn't seem to be correct:

```
function tryRemoveApplicationNode() {
  const currentApplicationNode = document.getElementsByTagName('ngk-app')[0];
  if (currentApplicationNode) {
    const parent = currentApplicationNode.parentNode;
    parent.removeChild(currentApplicationNode);
  }
}
```

Comment: Adding -1 without a comment is very constructive..

Comment: did you use `bootstrap` at prev version?i.e `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(your_module)`

Comment: A question about why is my code not working should contain the code.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer this has nothing to do with my code. The fact that I mentioned removing the node from the DOM doesn't mean that it is a proper solution that can be refined/upgraded and hence there's no point pasting it here.

Comment: @RachChen bootstrap as the name implies bootstraps the application and does not tear it down, so yes that's the way I'm bootstrapping the application, but I don't really see where you're going..

Comment: I still think it is likely it has. Providing your code would allow others to verify. I didn't downvote btw.

Comment: OK, I'll paste the code then :)

Answer (score 3):

At first you need the `@angularclass/hmr` package:

```
npm install @angularclass/hmr
```

This makes your life a bit easier.

You should call `destroy` on your `AppModule` in the `dispose` call of the `hot` module and after that use the `createNewHosts` method of the `@angularclass/hmr` package. You can try this as a `hmrBootstrap` function:

```
import {createNewHosts} from '@angularclass/hmr';
import {ApplicationRef, NgModuleRef} from '@angular/core';

export const hmrBootStrap: Function = async (): Promise<void> => {
    module['hot'].accept();
    const ngModule: NgModuleRef<AppModule> = await bootstrap();
    module['hot'].dispose(() => {
        const makeVisible: () => void = createNewHosts(
            ngModule.injector.get(ApplicationRef).components.map(
                c => c.location.nativeElement
            )
        );
        ngModule.destroy();
        makeVisible();
    });
};
```

And have a normal `bootstrap` method defined like this:

```
export const bootstrap: any = (): Promise<NgModuleRef<AppModule>> => {
    return platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule<AppModule>(AppModule);
};
```

And as a (partial) `main.ts` you can have this:

```
if (module.hot) {
    hmrBootStrap();
} else {
    bootstrap();
}
```

Comment: Angularclass/HMR is an overkill in all aspects and I specifically want to avoid using it. It obscures everything about HMR requiring their own webpack loader which is totally unnecessary. I already pasted 50% of the code that is necessary to use HMR. The only part that wasn't working properly (which I found out only two weeks ago) was the teardown. You can take a look here at my research regarding the use of HMR and what is really required. https://medium.com/@kubal5003/angular-4-hot-module-reload-explained-e832ea616304 I will update the article soon with the proper teardown..

Comment: Regarding your answer please cleanup the @angularclass/hmr part since the question is about Angular teardown. HMR is not the only scenario where you would want to teardown the Angular application. I will also cleanup my question from all signs of HMR in it.

Comment: Overkill would be a library with a lot of code.. this is just a couple of lines. Anyways, as far as I can see the removing and recreating of the application root cannot be decoupled. Have a look at their [`createNewHosts`](https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-hmr/blob/master/src/helpers.ts#L32) method. It seems to be all that you need

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that is required to properly teardown the Application is:

```
//save the NgModuleRef for later
let applicationModule = await platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);

//when it's time:
applicationModule.destroy();
```

My answer is based on the direction shown by @PierreDuc, but does not involve HMR of any kind. Putting it here only for the purpose of documenting.