# How to run same angular app multiple times?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a special use case where I need to be able to run an Angular app multiple time. I'm not in control of the page, it's a page rendered by a CMS.

The simple use case is this one : the user clicks on a button (Button A) and a modal is open which contains the my Angular app (`<my-app data-settings={...some settings...}></my-app>`) with its JS bundle. It's working really fine, not issue here.

The special use case I have is that the app should be able to be run again, another time, via another button (Button B) with another context (`<my-app data-settings={...different settings...}></my-app>`), not at the same time (one modal per page).

When I click on Button A, the apps render fine in the modal. I close the modal, and click on Button B, the modal opens but the app does not. Without any error in the console.

The app is pretty heavy with multiples components, multiple services, directives... (no Angular Router). The JS bundle is the same, it's injected once.

What I tried:
I tried compiling a hello world (ng new app), and render is on the page. It works fine.
I tried compiling my App into web Components (@angular/elements), it works but we need to support some older browser and I'm afraid it might not work for certain browsers.

What can I do to make it work ?

Comment: I think the issue might be the first app is not properly disposed.  Have you tried running the destroy method as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47472943/21398414 on closing the first modal?

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that Angular module is never destroyed. But I don't have access to the reference of the module from the outside...